# Why I'm getting 500 error in MVC 4.0 Web application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am a web developer,I used to do some updates on [website](https://www.preservawellness.com) developed in ASP .NET MVC 4.0

Recently we hosted eCommerce website on IIS 10.The website was running very slow, so I had to work for speed optimization, I have only work with images and file compression.

I also use Google web master tools for optimization, during optimization mostly we get 500 internal server error, some urls showing which has not been created yet.

Unfortunately, we are getting 500 error while proceed to Checkout Now. I am not able to figure out why i am getting 500 error? I didn't modify anything in Model and Controller, but i do some changes in View.

Here we proceed to Check Out Now.[https://www.preservawellness.com/shoppingcart/cart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9DKR.jpg)

Here the page is redirected to Payment options such as Net banking, Credit/debit, PayPal, Paytm
[https://www.preservawellness.com/ShoppingCart/OrderReview?subscriptionid=&Ptype=online&uid=282&Ctype=P](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9DKR.jpg)

When we click on "Place Order" Button The server returns 500 error which we are not able to diagnose. Below is the url after processing request(Place Order button) we are getting internal server error.

[https://www.preservawellness.com/ShoppingCart/ProcessToPayment/397](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZmeq.jpg)

Below is the page error details, we found on Chrome Developer Console(Network)

```
**Request URL:** https://www.preservawellness.com/ShoppingCart/ProcessToPayment/398
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 500 
Remote Address: 103.35.123.182:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
cache-control: private
content-length: 125200
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
date: Thu, 13 Dec 2018 06:11:23 GMT
server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0

**status: 500**

x-aspnet-version: 4.0.30319
x-aspnetmvc-version: 4.0
x-powered-by: ASP.NET
:authority: www.preservawellness.com

:**method: GET**

:path: /ShoppingCart/ProcessToPayment/398

:scheme: https
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
cache-control: max-age=0

cookie: G_ENABLED_IDPS=google; _ga=GA1.2.1980725648.1544503724; iztoken=; __unam=31c7a61-1679bfb9e68-35018d90-1; UserActivity=ProductID=54,34,35,15,23; _gid=GA1.2.898897304.1544674779; _fbp=fb.1.1544674779709.1169244464; izstatus=1; ASP.NET_SessionId=13itm5jbgar1edaviq1id2fl; __RequestVerificationToken=yg9rIfvgB1xkV_9RGhApwCQydRIbnLFwgh9VLplBUhKnjKmbvDu-Ct2AdANFxppppwPwAN-olzYQUf7sbQrQQ0Sa9KWl-NgPMYzFjI8lypCwrDhqpL8uNsFzK9Y5GeA1fyjSgntOPqluH6E1S3HQvQ2; ispopupopen=30; ispopupopens=10; _gat_gtag_UA_92955094_1=1
referer: https://www.preservawellness.com/ShoppingCart/OrderReview?subscriptionid=&Ptype=online&uid=282&Ctype=P
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.38 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15A372 Safari/604.1
```

Error Page: 
[page with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9DKR.jpg)

Comment: You would have to look in the server logs to find the exception.

Comment: Would you please elaborate steps how to check server log on IIS, i am new with IIS Hosting.

Comment: That depends on how your application handles logging. Might be a log file in the root folder of the app, or maybe App_Data. Can you reproduce the error locally? Otherwise, since you say that it worked before, then you changed something in the view and now it doesn't work, I would try to redo those changes one by one to find the one raising the exception.

Answer (score -2):

IIS must be using * instead of ip address and or host header